# Sigma Algebra Inclusion

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $S$ and $T$ be collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $S \subset T$. Let $\sigma(S)$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $S$ and let $\sigma(T)$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $T$.

Claim: $\sigma(S) \subset \sigma(T)$

Proof: Let $A \in \sigma(S)$, then $A$ is in any sigma algebra that contains $S$. This then implies that $A$ is in any sigma algebra that contains $T$ as $S \subset T$. Then $A$ is in the intersection of all sigma algebras containing $T$. Hence $A \in \sigma(T)$. Thus $\sigma(S) \subset \sigma(T)$.

Please let me know if my thought process is correct. If it is not correct, please help me fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning is even simpler: $\sigma(T)$ is *one* sigma-algebra that contains $S$, as $S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq \sigma(T)$. $\sigma(S)$ is the *smallest* such $\sigma$-algebra and so $\sigma(S) \subseteq \sigma(T)$.

Comment: I see! That is simpler. Does this mean however my logic was wrong?

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen you don't need to consider elements of $\sigma(S)$ at all. It doesn't add anything.